# jQuery - AJAX POST request and JSON Data - Working but Not Updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I'm working on my first `AJAX` `jQuery` script and I'm having trouble getting it to update some `HTML` elements with the result of the `AJAX POST request` - it's returning `JSON data` which I then use to update the 2 separate `HTML elements`.

Here's my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#templateRef").change(function() {
    var templateRef = $("#templateRef").val();
    var contactID = '<?php  echo $contactID; ?>';
    $.post('getEmailTemplate.php', {
      contactID: contactID,
      templateID: templateRef
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        alert("error");
        $("#emailBody").html('');
        $("#emailSubject").val('');
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        $("#emailBody").html(data.templateBody);
        $("#emailSubject").val(data.templateSubject);
      }

    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      $("#emailBody").html('');
      $("#emailSubject").val('');
    });
  });
});
```

I know the `POST` request is firing from looking at the web server logs but it looks like the issue is with these lines:

```
$("#emailBody").html(data.templateBody);
$("#emailSubject").val(data.templateSubject);
```

I'm not 100% clear if I have the correct syntax to process the `JSON data` response here into the separate `HTML elements`?

Comment: log those data attributes to the console to see if you're getting back what you expect. Also try data[0] as data can be a collection of json objects.

Comment: Please debug the code using the breakpoints to see that the correct data is coming or not.

Comment: Thanks @DubstepCat - it was the data[0] syntax. Once I change it to that it started working.